# how to pass parameters using auto redirect droplist in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, view, drop-down-menu

Hi guys Im trying to make a drop-down list of countries and when the user select a country that redirect to a specific page created dynamically actually i manage to make the redirection work using javascript, but i need to take more parameters to the method inside the controler like the county "id" with out exposing it on the uri, so is that possible using $_post also i should not use button submit.
this is my code

view page

```
<?php echo form_open('site/country');                 
  $options = array();
  $js = 'id="country" onChange="window.location.href= this.form.CTRY.options[this.form.CTRY.selectedIndex].value"';
  $options['#']  = "(please select a country)" ; 
  foreach ($list as $row):     
      $value= site_url()."/site/country/".url_title($row->name);
  $options[$value]  = $row->name ;   
  endforeach; 
  echo form_dropdown('CTRY', $options,'',$js);    
  //$test =array ('number' => 10)     
  //echo form_hidden($test);
  echo form_close();?>
```

this is my method in controller

```
function country($data)
   {
echo 'this is taking you to county= '.$data;

}
```

Comment: You can't POST with `window.location.href`. You need AJAX for that. May I suggest using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do something like @Joseph Silber described.

Use jQuery to perform an ajax request when the drop-down list is changed, also managing the redirect?

Something like;

```
$('#my-drop-down').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/site/country',
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#my-form").serialize(),
        success: function( response.redirect ) {
            window.location.href = response.redirect;
        },
        error: function( response ) {
            alert('Oops');
        }
    });
});
```

By using serilaize(), you can post all data from the form, or just add the parameters you want to pass.

E.g `data: 'id='+$('#id').val()+'&country='+$('#country').val()`